# python3.2 tkinter display an image from a URL

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to use tkinter on python 3.2 to display an image from the Internet.

I'm getting TypeError: 'HTTPResponse' object is not callable.I know that this means I'm referencing a variable or function incorrectly.
I have read [urllib "module object is not callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772190/urllib-module-object-is-not-callable) but I'm still not sure how to fix this problem. Your help is appreciated.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    #http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/diveintopython3/html/porting-code-              to-python-3-with-2to3.html
    import io

    img_file = urlopen('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png')
    im = io.FileIO(img_file())<<<<<<<<<<<<<this line is throwing the error
    resized_image = Image.open(im)
    im.show()

    root = tk.Tk()
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_image)
    panel = tk.Label(root, image = img)
    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `StringIO` object instead:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

...

im = StringIO(img_file.read())
```

It behaves like a file, but it's not a file.

Comment: I'm thankful for your speedy reply but when I run the code I get an error: UnsupportedOperation:Seek. I googled the error and most of the hits came back with I/O issues but I'm far from an expert. Your help is most valued. Here's the full error: http://pastebin.com/Ney0Lf0G

Comment: @pleabargain: Odd. Try using `StringIO`.