# Getting 'module' object is not callable while trying to run the following code

Tags: python-3.x

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Sudhir\workspace\Web App\cricbuzz.py", line 161, in <module> 
match = CricbuzzParser().getXml()
File "C:\Users\Sudhir\workspace\Web App\cricbuzz.py", line 20, in getXml
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) 
AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8"})
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**Code:**

```
import json
import urllib.request
import xml.dom.minidom

class CricbuzzParser():
def __init__(self):
    # self.getXml(url)
    pass

def getXml(self):
    # Change coding here
    r = urllib.request("http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml",
                        headers={
                            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8"})
    f = urllib.urlopen(r)
    doc = xml.dom.minidom.parse(f)
    node = doc.documentElement
    matches = node.getElementsByTagName("match")
    return matches

def handleMatches(self, matches):
    """This function handles the element <match> and
    avoids duplicate matches to be processed. """
    duplicate = []
    match_details = {}
    mchDesc = matches[0].getAttribute("mchDesc")
    duplicate.append(mchDesc)
    match_detail = self.handleMatch(matches[0])
    if match_detail is not None:
        match_details[match_detail["Team"]] = match_detail
    match_detail = self.handleTestMatch(matches[0])
    if match_detail is not None:
        match_details[match_detail["Team"]] = match_detail
    for match in matches:
        flag = False
        mchDesc = match.getAttribute("mchDesc")
        # If list duplicate is empty, then populate it initially.
        for entry in duplicate:
            if entry == mchDesc:  # If duplicate is found
                flag = True
        if flag is not True:
            duplicate.append(mchDesc)
            match_detail = self.handleMatch(match)
            if match_detail is not None:
                match_details[match_detail["Team"]] = match_detail
            match_detail = self.handleTestMatch(match)
            if match_detail is not None:
                match_details[match_detail["Team"]] = match_detail
    return match_details

def handleTestMatch(self, match):
    """For handling Test Matches.
    To Do: Write Code for Parsing Innings detail"""
    series = match.getAttribute("srs")
    mtype = match.getAttribute("type")
    if mtype != "TEST":
        return None
    else:
        inngs = []
        match_desc = match.getAttribute("mchDesc")
        mground = match.getAttribute("grnd")
        match_of_the_series = match.getAttribute("mnum")
        states = match.getElementsByTagName("state")
        batting_team = match.getElementsByTagName("btTm")
        bowling_team = match.getElementsByTagName("blgTm")
        batting_team_name = batting_team[0].getAttribute("sName")
        bowling_team_name = bowling_team[0].getAttribute("sName")
        bowling_innings = bowling_team[0].getElementsByTagName("Inngs")
        batting_innings = batting_team[0].getElementsByTagName("Inngs")

        for i in range(len(batting_innings)):
            bat_runs = {"Runs": batting_innings[i].getAttribute("r")}
            bat_overs = {"Overs": batting_innings[i].getAttribute("ovrs")}
            bat_wkts = {"Wickets": batting_innings[i].getAttribute("wkts")}
            desc1 = {"Desc": batting_innings[i].getAttribute("desc")}
            inngs_detail = [desc1, bat_runs, bat_wkts, bat_overs]
            inngs.append(inngs_detail)
        inngs.insert(0, "Team:" + batting_team_name)
        batting_team_inngs = inngs
        inngs = []

        for i in range(len(bowling_innings)):
            bowl_runs = {"Runs": bowling_innings[i].getAttribute("r")}
            bowl_overs = {"Overs": bowling_innings[i].getAttribute("ovrs")}
            bowl_wkts = {"Wickets": bowling_innings[i].getAttribute("wkts")}
            desc1 = {"Desc": bowling_innings[i].getAttribute("desc")}
            inngs_detail = [desc1, bowl_runs, bowl_wkts, bowl_overs]
            inngs.append(inngs_detail)
        inngs.insert(0, "Team:" + bowling_team_name)
        bowling_team_inngs = inngs

        for state in states:
            match_cstate = state.getAttribute("mchState")
            mstatus = state.getAttribute("status")
            if mstatus.startswith("Starts") or mstatus.startswith("Coming"):
                return None  # Match hasn't started Yet.

    return {"Series": series, "Match Format": "TEST", "Team": match_desc, "Venue": mground,
            "Match State": match_cstate, "Match Status": mstatus,
            "Match Details": {"Batting Team": batting_team_inngs, "Bowling Team": bowling_team_inngs}}

def handleMatch(self, match):
    """Handles ODI and T20 matches"""
    bowl_runs = None
    bowl_wkts = None
    bowl_overs = None
    series = match.getAttribute("srs")
    mtype = match.getAttribute("type")
    if mtype == "TEST":
        return None
    match_desc = match.getAttribute("mchDesc")
    mground = match.getAttribute("grnd")
    states = match.getElementsByTagName("state")
    for state in states:
        match_cstate = state.getAttribute("mchState")
        mstatus = state.getAttribute("status")
        if mstatus.startswith("Starts") or mstatus.startswith("Coming"):
            return None  # Match hasn't started Yet.
    try:
        batting_team = match.getElementsByTagName("btTm")
        bowling_team = match.getElementsByTagName("blgTm")
        batting_team_name = batting_team[0].getAttribute("sName")
        bowling_team_name = bowling_team[0].getAttribute("sName")
        innings = match.getElementsByTagName("Inngs")
        bat_runs = innings[0].getAttribute("r")
        bat_overs = innings[0].getAttribute("ovrs")
        bat_wkts = innings[0].getAttribute("wkts")
    except Exception:
        # Match is comple. Only Result is availabe now and btTm tag has been changed to Tm
        # So, now only status of the match is important. Initialize none to other parameters.
        batting_team = None
        bowling_team = None
        batting_team_name = None
        bowling_team_name = None
        innings = None
        bat_runs = None
        bat_overs = None
        bat_wkts = None
    try:
        bowl_runs = innings[1].getAttribute("r")
        bowl_overs = innings[1].getAttribute("ovrs")
        bowl_wkts = innings[1].getAttribute("wkts")
    except Exception:
        # The opponent team hasn't yet started to Bat.
        pass
    return {"Series": series, "Match Format": mtype, "Team": match_desc, "Venue": mground,
            "Match State": match_cstate, "Match Status": mstatus, "Batting team": batting_team_name,
            "Bowling team": bowling_team_name, "Batting Team Runs": bat_runs, "Batting Team Overs": bat_overs,
            "Batting Team Wickets": bat_wkts, "Bowling Team Runs": bowl_runs, "Bowling Team Overs": bowl_overs,
            "Bowling Team Wickets": bowl_wkts}

if __name__ == '__main__':
cric = CricbuzzParser()
match = cric.getXml()
details = cric.handleMatches(match)  # Returns Match details as a Dictionary. Parse it according to requirements.
with open("data.json", "w") as dataFile:
    dataFile.write(json.dumps(details))
```

Comment: Did you paste the correct indentation? It looks like the indentation is off under the CricbuzzParser class.

Comment: Sir, indentation is correct in the code file. Here it is not coming out as in the file. I can send you the code file, if required. Assume 4 spaces for each def function and subsequent statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [urllib "module object is not callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772190/urllib-module-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `urllib.request` is a module, so when you do this:

```
r = urllib.request("http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml",
                        headers={
                            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8"})
```

You are trying to call the module, hence the error message.
Did you mean to use `urllib.request.Request()`? See the docs for more info: https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request

Also, see this identical question: [urllib "module object is not callable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772190/urllib-module-object-is-not-callable)